# Auto-Rig a character with another tool like maya and import the mesh and the armature in blender?

Tags: modeling, rigging, export, import, external-applications

I'm looking for a good tool to auto rig the characters made in Blender in a few clicks. I found some great `auto-rigging tools`,like `auto-rig pro` or `radiant rig XL`,but they aren't perfect. I mean that I should make some manual adjustements to reach the perfection and it takes some time. So,I thought...what about if :

1. I create the character in blender
2. I export the character in maya (for example)
3. I find a good auto-rigging tool for maya
4. I export the mesh and the armature in maya and I import them in
   blender

So,I did some research and I found this [auto-rigging tool](http://www.animationstudios.com.au/advanced-skeleton-download). I would like to know if I can do what I explained and how can I do it. Thanks.

Comment: When you say you have seen some tools are you talking [rigify](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify) and [blenrig](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/)?

Comment: No,I'm talking about auto-rig,like auto-rig pro or radiant rig XL...